# Java Regular Expression To Find PDF Files

Tags: java

Need help figure out how to tweak the below regular expression

Now we are using  `[0-9]+\.pdf` to identify PDF files that starts with just a numbers “3005183198.pdf”

Now the files names have been changed to new format and i am not sure how to account for it.

What would the regular expression be to find a file pattern like this?

“3005183198.md515114F47DFD62791AC4C87527CED1AA5.PDF”

I know i should start with "[0-9]+" and end with `\.pdf` just not sure what i need to add to account for "." and the unknown string of letter and numbers.

Comment: In file name before `.PDF` anything name can be written?(anything means any character, special character,digits)

Comment: .+.pdf? Usually . matches any non-whitespace character

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

> “[0-9]+.*\\.pdf”

Comment: The filename contains letters, so your pattern doesn't cover everything

Comment: .* covers letters.  the beginning of it is numbers.

Comment: After alphanumeric pattern, there should be one dot character according to given example.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern doesn't work if the filename really ends with `.PDF` because you only check for the lowercase variant. When you compile a pattern you can pass certain flags, so what you need should be covered by the following code:

```
Pattern pdfCheck = Pattern.compile("^.*\\.pdf$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alphanumeric regex:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

OR

```
"^.+$"
```

Numeric regex:

```
"^[0-9]+$"
```

OR

```
"^\\d+$"
```

Dot regex:

```
"^\\.$"
```

Your regex:

```
"^\\d+\\..+\\.pdf$"
```

One or more numeric char + exactly one dot + one or more alphanumeric char + ".pdf"

Answer (score 0):

The expression you need to match your file names should be the following:

```
boolean res = testString.matches("[0-9]+[.][0-9A-Za-z]+[.][Pp][Dd][Ff]");
```

Use [.] to match the dot :)

Please tell me if I've been of help! :)